# Java. Задача на многопоточность

Tags: java, многопоточность

> Напишите код, в котором создаются и запускаются на выполнение потоки S и W. Поток S выполняет переключение с задержкой 1000 миллисекунд из состояния true в состояние false и наоборот. Поток W ожидает состояния true потока S, выводит на консоль обратный отсчет от 30 с задержкой 100 миллисекунд и приостанавливает свое действие, как только поток S переключен в состояние false. Условием завершения работы потоков является достижение отсчета нулевой отметки.

Мое нерабочее решение:

```
public class S extends Thread {
    Sobj sobj;

    public S(Sobj sobj) {
        this.sobj = sobj;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ChangeState(this.sobj);
    }

    public void ChangeState(Sobj s) {
        while(true){
            synchronized (s) {
                if (!s.state) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    s.state = true;
                    s.notify();
                }
                else{
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    s.state = false;
                }
                System.out.println(s.state);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class W extends Thread {
    Sobj sobj;

    public W(Sobj sobj) {
        this.sobj = sobj;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Countdown(this.sobj);
    }

    public void Countdown(Sobj s) {
        synchronized (s) {
            while (!s.state) {
                try {
                    s.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            for (int i = 30; i >= 0; i--) {
                System.out.println("The countdown is: " + i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Sobj {
    boolean state;

    public Sobj() {
        this.state = true;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sobj sobj = new Sobj();
        S S = new S(sobj);
        W W = new W(sobj);
        S.start();
        W.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы блокируете объект и засыпаете. Вторая нить не может исполняться так как не может получить доступ к объекту.

Answer (score 0):

Решение через volatile

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Task2 {
    static volatile boolean switcher = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       Thread thread1 =  new Thread( () -> {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                    switcher = !switcher;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        });
       thread1.setDaemon(true);

       Thread thread2 = new Thread( () -> {
            int i = 30;
            while (i >= 0) {
              //  while (true) {
                    if (switcher) {
                        try {
                            System.out.println(i);
                            i--;
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                //    }
                }
            }
       });
       thread1.start();
       thread2.start();
    }
}
```